# How to add and retrieve data from NSDictionary inside a view controller

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to cache some images in my view controller using NSDictionary but I'm not having much luck.

for starters my .h looks like this

```
...
  NSDictionary *images;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *images;
```

and in my .m I synth the property and attempt to add the image as follows:

```
[self.images setValue:img forKey:@"happy"];
```

and later I attempt to grab the image by key

```
UIImage *image = [self.images objectForKey:@"happy"];
    if (!image) {
      NSLog(@"not cached");
    }else {
      NSLog(@"had cached img %@", image);
    }
```

Yet each time I NSLog the dictionary it's null. If I @synthesize the property should I be ready to go out of the box? or did I not add this to the dictionary correctly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synthesizing doesn't instantiate the variable so you still need to alloc+init it at some point.

But if you want to add objects to a dictionary after creating it, you need to use `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

Then alloc+init it in viewDidLoad using something like:

```
self.images = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10] autorelease];
```

Then to set a value, use `setObject:forKey:` (not `setValue:forKey:`):

```
[images setObject:img forKey:@"happy"];
```

Remember to release the dictionary in dealloc.

Comment: That was the exact issue - thanks for taking the time to help out another geek on a Sat night :)